# Advice for where to start when choosing and working with a touch screen display for the first time

Tags: pic, display, touchscreen

I am looking to utilize a touch screen display in an ongoing project and have not ever had to use one before so I am starting from ground zero. I was hoping to get some general advice on what to start with in terms of understanding the protocols used in pushing images to the screen, receiving inputs from the screen, hardware, voltage levels, etc etc so any links to resources, guides, or well-documented products would be greatly, greatly appreciated. I am doing my research into various units made by Adafruit, Mikroe, Microchip (PIC32 devices) and see videos [like this one](https://youtu.be/kahtMBanZr8) showing that the SAM D51 can drive such a screen all by itself but its just a demo and so I am not getting a great understanding on the path forward but I will be going through the Adafruit guide soon. In terms of tech specs, I have a 5V supply feeding the electronics and am familiar with programming PIC devices and is my preferred series of devices.

To clarify, I am looking for advice or anything you guys can offer to help focus my research and efforts to understanding what I will need to design the interface and code.

Specific questions I have are:

1. Do you have any recommendations for a 5V powered touch screen (3-6 in) that can be controlled using a PIC controller? I believe resistive and or simpler screens will work, it just has to be able to register button presses in order to begin an automatic program which runs motors, receives data, etc etc.
2. Do you need additional memory (SD cards) when running some simple GUI menus?
3. Is there a common interface type from the main controller to the display controller? I see I2C has come up a lot, some 4-5 wire or 8-bit streams but not sure which is best or easiest to use for GUI.
4. Do you need to have some software library for each display that loads images or are images still generally written using coordinates and pixel-by-pixel writing, similar to what one has to do with one of the [TFT Adafruit displays](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2050?gclid=Cj0KCQiA0eOPBhCGARIsAFIwTs5zuoLiejolrx9zcvsQRP5jwjwLmwBjo7GXtXJ1dIt5jJaVUNTPY4UaAu6qEALw_wcB)?

Comment: Get an LCD module where you just send it drawing command and it does the work for you.

Comment: Start from data sheets reading.

Comment: My suggestion? Use a display that already does the hard work for you. Like displays from 4d systems or mikroe for example

Comment: the touch panel and the LCD are two independent devices

Comment: @VoltageSpike I had not heard of 4D systems, I will check them out and go look through Mikroe’s stuff more.

Comment: There are more, do a through search and see what works for you. You should look for displays with an attached controller. Many display companies will also provide software to build a gui on the display.

Comment: Excellent, and I can talk to the graphics controller with a PIC via SPI or I2C (or whatever 4 or 8 wire system it uses) then correct? It sounds like the more decisive factor in choosing the main controller then is going to be requirements relating to needing to add Bluetooth as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sorry, recommendations are off-topic
2. No, SD card is not necessary if you can fit your graphics data within MCU, but if you can't fit your data into MCU, you can store the data on SD card or any other media you like. We can't guess how much data you have or need or which MCU you have so we can't say if you need it.
3. No there is no common interface. Each display controller may have only one or several different interfaces - I2C, few different kind of SPI interfaces, Intel or Motorola style parallel buses of various widths, and RGB graphics port of various widths. The actual display module may only allow one or few of the available interfaces. Even if many displays have same interface, the protocol or commands may be wildly different.
4. No you don't need a separate library, you can write your own with the commands that are available from that specific display. Different displays may have different or multiple native data block loading features available for loading data. Writing a single pixel at a time will be slow, but most likely your first program initializes the display and writes a single pixel to demostrate you got it right.

Comment: That was a very informative reply, thank you. I didn’t realize recommendations like that were off topic, will keep that in mind for the future. That helps clarify a great deal regarding my specific points.